# Double th numpy array in order

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Could you tell me how to resize the array in order?
For example:

If the input is:

```
>>> np.arange(4)
array([0, 1, 2, 3])
```

The output will be:

```
array([0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: a = np.arange(4)

In [3]: a
Out[3]: array([0, 1, 2, 3])

In [4]: np.repeat(a, 2)
Out[4]: array([0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3])
```

Comment: adding more explanation to your answer would make it better